# Oracle: when was my table modifed?

Tags: oracle

I have some configuration information in some tables that need to get dumped to some flat files.

What's the best way to detect that the tables have changed?  I don't have control of some of these tables, so I would prefer to avoid a trigger if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2097.htm) view, which is populated for tables with MONITORING enabled. It may no be 100% up-to-date, but you can run a stored procedure to flush the most recent data.

And then there is [ORA_ROWSCN](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/pseudocolumns006.htm), which is a conservative upper bound system change number for when the row was last updated.

```
 select scn_to_timestamp(max(ora_rowscn)) from table_name
```